# Jquery ajax not working in bootstrap modal

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I tried using jquery ajax to send a request to a php file, but it wasn't working.
I've searched many topics to see if they could be of help but all to no avail.

Here is my code.

NOTE: the variable are well declared but to save time, I may not be able to post them all because they are fetched from the database.

```
foreach($fetch_products as $row)
{
    $i++;
    $start_from = $i+$offset;
    $super_id = $row['super_id'];
    $super_name = $row['name'];

    ?>
   <div class="modal inmodal" id="EditModal<?php echo $super_id;?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
       <div class="modal-content animated flipInY">
           <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit <?php echo $super_name;?></h4>
          </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
              <form id="update_super_product_form<?php echo $super_id;?>" action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                <input type="hidden" name="super_id" value="<?php echo $super_id;?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="current_page" value="<?php echo $current_page;?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="per_page" value="<?php echo $per_page;?>"/>
                <label>Product name</label>
                <input type="text" name="product_name" id="product_name" value="<?php echo $super_name;?>" class="form-control"> 
                                        <br/>

                                    <div id="update_super_product_status<?php echo $super_id;?>"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> Close</button>
                                    <button type="submit" id="update_super_product_btn<?php echo $super_id;?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save changes</button>
                                </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

      <script type='text/javascript'>
        $("#update_super_product_form<?php echo $super_id;?>").submit(function(e)
                        {
                            e.preventDefault();

                            var current_page = "<?php echo $current_page;?>";
                            var per_page = "<?php echo $per_page;?>";
                            var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);
                            var btn = $("#update_super_product_btn<?php echo $super_id;?>");
                            var status = $("#update_super_product_status<?php echo $super_id;?>");

                            $.ajaxSetup(
                            {
                                beforeSend:function()
                                {
                                    btn.attr("disabled",true);
                                    btn.html("Please wait <img src='img/loading.gif'/>");
                                    alert("xx");
                                },
                                complete:function()
                                {
                                    btn.attr("disabled",false);
                                    btn.html("<i class='fa fa-check'></i> Save changes");
                                    alert("xxx");
                                }
                            });

                            $.ajax(
                            {
                                type: "POST",
                                data: data,
                                url: "gotcha.php?UpdateSuperProduct",
                                cache:false,

                                success: function(msg)
                                {
                                    status.fadeIn("");
                                    status.html(msg).delay(4000).fadeOut("slow");
                                    btn.attr("disabled", false);
                                }
                            });
                        });


                    </script>
```

I'll be glad if you help.
Thanks

Comment: Any errors in the console? What's your network tab's status when you open the modal?

Comment: No error in console sir.

Comment: Okay great. Now clear your network tab. Keep it open. Click on the bootstrap modal window trigger to open the bootstrap. Do you see any change in the network tab?

Comment: No changes sir.

Comment: Ah... Something is seriously wrong buddy. Unable to solve your issue just with the information you have provided so far.

Comment: And please, don't use `sir`.

Comment: smiles, alright. Thanks

Comment: Is that ajax call working properly, outside of the modal?